How to derive missing parameters for modified nucleosides (OL15/OL21)
I am new to molecular dynamics and am currently working on modified DNA/RNA nucleosides, derived from the OL21 and OL15 available templates, respectively. I would like to stick with these force fields instead of GAFF2, but I am wondering if it's reasonable to use GAFF2-generated parameters if the DNA/RNA forcefields  cannot find them and yield “ATTN, needs revision”.
Alternatively —and maybe that’s even more wise — I could derive parameters using QM calculations. OL21 seems to be primarily based on parm99 (Figure 1 of https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.3c00233). According to the Amber24 manual and related studies:

https://doi.org/10.1002/1096-987X(200009)21:12<1049::AID-JCC3>3.0.CO;2-F
https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.540161106
https://doi.org/10.1021/ct600329w,

it seems that HF/6-31G(d) was used. I must not use a higher-level quantum theory, such as PBE0-D4/def2-TZVP for scans and fitting, as it might introduce inconsistencies. Is my understanding correct
Thanks
